# Stop R write.xlsx from turning wide data to long

Tags: r, xlsx

I need to output data to xlsx, and the XLSX package seemed to be widely used.

However, using it seems to turn wide data to long data. I would like to keep the data wide when it exports to Excel.

```
library(xlsx)

myTable <- xtabs(mpg~carb+cyl, mtcars)

myTable

write.xlsx(myTable, "myFile.xlsx")
```

The above code is a minimal example that will demonstrate the problem.

The console will output myTable, as per the below:

```
> myTable
    cyl
carb     4     6     8
   1 137.9  39.5   0.0
   2 155.4   0.0  68.6
   3   0.0   0.0  48.9
   4   0.0  79.0  78.9
   6   0.0  19.7   0.0
   8   0.0   0.0  15.0
```

However, the Excel file will have the same data in long format, as per below:

```
    carb    cyl Freq
1   1   4   137.9
2   2   4   155.4
3   3   4   0
4   4   4   0
5   6   4   0
6   8   4   0
7   1   6   39.5
8   2   6   0
9   3   6   0
10  4   6   79
11  6   6   19.7
12  8   6   0
13  1   8   0
14  2   8   68.6
15  3   8   48.9
16  4   8   78.9
17  6   8   0
18  8   8   15
```

If anyone could help me understand why this is happening or how to correct it, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Wrap it in `as.data.frame.matrix` before trying to write your file.

Comment: That worked. I lost the column and row title, but it worked. Any way to keep those?

Comment: Also, I would have thought that the output from an xtabs call was already a matrix. According to typeof(), it is a double, and the output from the as.data.frame.matrix() is a list. Is there a post or site that can shed light on these differences? Neither of them is coming back as a type of matrix, which is confusing to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the "details" section at `?write.xlsx`, it mentions:

> If x is not a data.frame it will be converted to one.

I presume it does so using `as.data.frame`.

When a `table` object is converted to a `data.frame` using `as.data.frame`, the original structure of the table is changed into a "long" format, and that's what you are seeing here.

To get around this, use `as.data.frame.matrix`, like this:

```
write.xlsx(as.data.frame.matrix(myTable), "myFile.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any way to keep the row and column names? Also, is there anywhere I can go to understand the data types better? I have seen the basic data types, but am confused as to why I'm seeing data types of double and list, instead of matrix?

Comment: @JohnTarr, if you're referring to the "cyl" and "carb", I don't think that you'll be able to retain those. Also check out `class` and `str` for different ways to find out about your data types.

Comment: Ok, it should be intuitive enough what I'm trying to display without the names. I forgot about class and str, those do shed additional light on the data types. Thanks!